# Check if file exists [BASH]

Tags: bash, shell

How do I check if file exists in bash?

When I try to do it like this:

```
FILE1="${@:$OPTIND:1}"
if [ ! -e "$FILE1" ]
then 
    echo "requested file doesn't exist" >&2
    exit 1
elif
<more code follows>
```

I always get following output:

```
 requested file doesn't exist
```

The program is used like this:

```
script.sh [-g] [-p] [-r FUNCTION_ID|-d FUNCTION_ID] FILE
```

Any ideas please?
I will be glad for any help.

P.S. I wish I could show the entire file without the risk of being fired from school for having a duplicate. If there is a private method of communication I will happily oblige.

My mistake. Fas forcing a binary file into a wrong place. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Do you see correct path if you add `echo "$FILE1"` before `if` ?

Comment: No, I see an empty space.

Comment: then file "" does not exist..

Comment: When I do ls I can clearly see it. When I do ls I can clearly see it.

Comment: the file with empty name can't exist. check the `FILE1="${@:$OPTIND:1}` for correctness.

Comment: @user3473750: When you do `ls` you can clearly see *what*? The problem is that you're expecting `"${@:$OPTIND:1}"` to contain a valid file name; instead, it contains an empty string (or is unset). Naturally a file whose name is the empty string does not exist. You need to figure out why `"${@:$OPTIND:1}"` doesn't contain the value you expect it to -- and you haven't given us enough information to help with that.

Comment: ls
callgraph.gv   Makefile           print_recursive.o  recursive.c  symbols.png
callgraph.png  Makefile.dep       recfun             recursive.h  timeout.c
depcg.sh       print_recursive.c  recfun.c           recursive.o  timeout.h
d.sh           print_recursive.h  recfun.o           symbols.gv   timeout.o

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong with your use of `getopts`, and `${@:$OPTIND:1}` doesn't refer to the argument you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To (recap) and add to @DavidW.'s excellent answer:

- **Check the shebang line** (first line) of your script to ensure that it's executed by `bash`: is it `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`?
- Inspect your script file for **hidden control characters** (such as `\r`) that can result in unexpected behavior; run `cat -v scriptFile | fgrep ^` - it should produce NO output; if the file does contain `\r` chars., they would show as `^M`.

  - To remove the `\r` instances (more accurately, to convert Windows-style `\r\n` newline sequences to Unix `\n`-only sequences), you can use `dos2unix file` to convert *in place*; if you don't have this utility, you can use `sed 's/'$'\r''$//' file > outfile` (CAVEAT: use a DIFFERENT output file, otherwise you'll destroy your input file); to remove *all* `\r` instances (even if not followed by `\n`), use `tr -d '\r' < file > outfile`  (CAVEAT: use a DIFFERENT output file, otherwise you'll destroy your input file).

- In addition to @DavidW.'s great debugging technique, you can add the following to **visually inspect all arguments** passed to your script:

```bsh
i=0; for a; do echo "\$$((i+=1))=[$a]"; done
```

(The purpose of enclosing the value in `[...]` (for example), is to see the exact boundaries of the values.)

This will yield something like:

```
$1=[-g]
$2=[input.txt]
...
```

Note, though, that nothing at all is printed if no arguments were passed.

Comment: I am using #!/usr/bin/env bash and I have plenty of ^M

Comment: ./depcg.sh -r timeout.o
$1=[-r]
$2=[timeout.o]
-r timeout.o
File doesn't exist.

Comment: @user3473750: (a) you should remove the `\r` (`^M`) chars. from your script - see my updated answer; (b) even though it seems that your arguments are passed in OK per se, there's a problem with accessing `timeout.o` via `${@:$OPTIND:1}` - to narrow down the problem, use `$2` in place of `${@:$OPTIND:1}` and see if that works.

Comment: How do I remove \r chars? Geany is not letting me do that. :(

Comment: See my updated answer (`dos2unix`, if available; else use the `sed` or `tr` command).

Comment: tr -d '\r' < depcg.sh > depcg.sh completely wiped the file......thanks..I guess...

Comment: I'm sorry to hear it. Note how my example uses `outfile`, a file DIFFERENT from the INPUT file to prevent just that - what you ran into is an unfortunate, but very basic shell pitfall (output files are truncated before command execution begins). I've added a caveat to my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Little trick to debugging problems like this. Add these lines to the top of your script:

```
export PS4="\$LINENO: "
set -xv
```

The `set -xv` will print out each line before it is executed, and then the line once the shell interpolates variables, etc. The `$PS4` is the prompt used by `set -xv`. This will print the line number of the shell script as it executes. You'll be able to follow what is going on and where you may have problems.

Here's an example of a test script:

```
#! /bin/bash

export PS4="\$LINENO: "
set -xv

FILE1="${@:$OPTIND:1}"         # Line 6
if [ ! -e "$FILE1" ]           # Line 7
then 
    echo "requested file doesn't exist" >&2
    exit 1
else
    echo "Found File $FILE1"   # Line 12
fi
```

And here's what I get when I run it:

```
$ ./test.sh .profile
    FILE1="${@:$OPTIND:1}"
6: FILE1=.profile
    if [ ! -e "$FILE1" ]
    then 
        echo "requested file doesn't exist" >&2
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Found File $FILE1"
    fi
7: [ ! -e .profile ]
12: echo 'Found File .profile'
Found File .profile
```

Here, I can see that I set `$FILE1` to `.profile`, and that my script understood that `${@:$OPTIND:1}`. The best thing about this is that it works on all shells down to the original Bourne shell. That means if you aren't running Bash as you think you might be, you'll see where your script is failing, and maybe fix the issue.

I suspect you might not be running your script in Bash. Did you put `#! /bin/bash` on the top?

---

> script.sh [-g] [-p] [-r FUNCTION_ID|-d FUNCTION_ID] FILE

You may want to use `getopts` to parse your parameters:

```
#! /bin/bash

USAGE=" Usage:
    script.sh [-g] [-p] [-r FUNCTION_ID|-d FUNCTION_ID] FILE
"
while getopts gpr:d: option
do
    case $option in
        g)  g_opt=1;;
        p)  p_opt=1;;
        r)  rfunction_id="$OPTARG";;
        d)  dfunction_id="$OPTARG";;
        [?])
            echo "Invalid Usage" 1>&2
            echo "$USAGE"        1>&2
            exit 2
            ;;
    esac
done

if [[ -n $rfunction_id && -n $dfunction_id ]]
then
    echo "Invalid Usage: You can't specify both -r and -d" 1>&2
    echo "$USAGE" >2&
    exit 2
fi

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
[[ -n $g_opt ]] && echo "-g was set"
[[ -n $p_opt ]] && echo "-p was set"
[[ -n $rfunction_id ]] && echo "-r was set to $rfunction_id"
[[ -n $dfunction_id ]] && echo "-d was set to $dfunction_id"
[[ -n $1 ]] && echo "File is $1"
```

Comment: I put #!/usr/bin/env bash on the top

Comment: @user3473750 - Obviously, you're not setting `$FILE1` With the line number as _69_, I suspect that maybe `FILE1="${@:$OPTIND:1}"` isn't working as you think it should. What is the value of `$@` at this point? Maybe a file name isn't being passed to your script. Maybe you've pulled out more than you think. See my script on how to use `getopt` and how I adjust `$@` with `shift` afterwords.

Comment: The $@ contains "-r timeout.o"

Comment: @user3473750: To enumerate all arguments passed to your script for visual inspection, add `for a; do echo "[$a]"; done`. (The `[...]` is just to see the exact boundaries of your values.)

Comment: Does `$@` contain `-r timeout.o` at the beginning of the script or right before you assign `$FILE1`? I suspect that you are using `getopts` since you're using `$OPTIND`. In that case, `-r timeout.o` `$OPTIND` would include the `-r` and the `timeout.o`. It would be set to 3 which means that your not pointing to a file name. Use `shift = $((OPTIND - 1))` and verify that `$1` still has a value.

Comment: The PS4 thingy is cute, but falls down when using something so advanced as "functions".  I like:  PS4='>${FUNCNAME:-script}> ' == which can be augmented with '$LINE' if you like, but usually not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to print FILE1 to see if it has the value you want, if it is not the problem, here is a simple script (site below):

```
#!/bin/bash
file="${@:$OPTIND:1}"
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."
else
    echo "$file not found."
fi
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-test-existence-of-file-in-bash/

Comment: I always get not found.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of plucking an item out of "$@" in a tricky way, why don't you `shift` off the args you've processed with getopts:

```
while getopts ...
done

shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

FILE1=$1
```