# How to remove files with certain string

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm struggling with the problem of deleting files after some processing. I am generating pcap files, then do processing and finally in the `/home/marcin/workspace/bake/source/ns-3.19/RESULTS/TRAFFIC_LIGHTS/_udp_filtered/`  directory I have files like below:

> `1.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap`
>
> `1_00000_19700101010009_udp_filtered.pcap`
>
> `3.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap`
>
> `3_00000_19700101010009_udp_filtered.pcap`

Then i would like to delete all the files that include `$nodeID.pcap` at the beggining of the name.
It work just for the last file in the loop. In this case only `3.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap` is deleted. Do you have any suggestions where should I put the "rm" line in the code to make it working for all the `$nodeIDs`

```
#!/bin/sh

#SETTING parameters to generate feature vectors

#set the directory of the initial .pcap files"
hdir=/home/marcin/workspace/bake/source/ns-3.19/RESULTS/TRAFFIC_LIGHTS/
files=/$hdir/*
udp_fil_dir=/$hdir/_udp_filtered/*
mac_sorted_dir=/$hdir/_udp_filtered/_MAC_sorted/*


#set <src> for source mac address (outcoming packets) or `<dst>` for destination source mac address (incoming packets)
ether_direction=src


#RENAMING the files

printf "...RENAMING the files to get proper nodeID...\n"

cd $hdir
ls aodv*|awk -F\. '{print;split($1,a,"-");c=a[2]+1;print c""FS""$2}'|xargs -n2 mv


for n in $files
    do

        export fspec2=./"$n" 
        fname2=`basename $fspec2`
        nodeID="${fname2%%.*}"  #nodeID is the variable that handles all the node numbers from directory 


        echo $nodeID
    
        mac_address="00:00:00:00:00:0$nodeID"
        echo $mac_address
        editcap -i 1 "$nodeID.pcap" "$nodeID"

#FILTERING only UDP packets from pcap file stored in a specific folder

        printf "...FILTERING only UDP packets from pcap files stored in a specific folder...\n"
        
        for f in $files
        do
            tshark -Y "udp&&!aodv" -r "$f" -w ""$f"_udp_filtered".pcap
            mkdir $hdir/_udp_filtered
            mv  ""$f"_udp_filtered".pcap $hdir/_udp_filtered
        find /home/marcin/workspace/bake/source/ns-3.19/RESULTS/TRAFFIC_LIGHTS/_udp_filtered/ -name "$nodeID.pcap*" -exec rm {} \;
        done

    done
```

Comment: Just curious (don't fully understand your code): why do you process the same set of files again in an inner `for` loop? At the very least, putting the `find` command inside the inner loop doesn't make sense.

Comment: because the content of `$files` folder does change during the data process. When I work with one loop only, I cannot get the output I need. `find` command does not work both in the inner and the outer `for` loop. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally:

- There's too much going on in your code (unused 'constants', variables, nonstandard utilities, ...) - narrow the problem down - both for your sake and for the sake of people potentially willing to help here.
  See [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22720888/45375 for general `bash` debugging tips.

Below is a cleaned-up version of your code that may at least *help* solve the problem; I've added comments marked with `# !!` where I've made changes (minor changes, such as double-quoting variable references for robustness, are not explicitly marked).

You say you do need the inner loop, so I've kept it - I suspect there is potential for refactoring, but I don't understand enough of what's going on.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# !! ^ Since your question is bash-tagged, use a *bash* shebang.

#SETTING parameters to generate feature vectors

#set the directory of the initial .pcap files"
hdir=/home/marcin/workspace/bake/source/ns-3.19/RESULTS/TRAFFIC_LIGHTS
# !! ^ terminal / removed, because you later synthesize paths explicitly with /
files=$hdir/*  # !! initial / removed, because $hdir is already an absolute path
udp_fil_dir=$hdir/_udp_filtered/* # !! ditto
mac_sorted_dir=$hdir/_udp_filtered/_MAC_sorted/* # !! ditto

#set <src> for source mac address (outcoming packets) or `<dst>` for destination source mac address (incoming packets)
ether_direction=src

#RENAMING the files

printf "...RENAMING the files to get proper nodeID...\n"

cd "$hdir"
ls aodv* | awk -F\. '{print;split($1,a,"-");c=a[2]+1;print c FS $2}' | xargs -n2 mv


for n in $files
do

  export fspec2=./"$n" 
  fname2=$(basename "$fspec2")
  nodeID="${fname2%%.*}"  #nodeID is the variable that handles all the node numbers from directory 

  echo "$nodeID"

  mac_address="00:00:00:00:00:0$nodeID"
  echo "$mac_address"

  editcap -i 1 "$nodeID.pcap" "$nodeID"

  printf "...FILTERING only UDP packets from pcap files stored in a specific folder...\n"

  for f in $files
  do
      tshark -Y "udp&&!aodv" -r "$f" -w "${f}_udp_filtered".pcap 
      # !! ^ use `${f}` rather than `"${f}"` (extra set of double quotes)
      # !!   to delineate variable names inside double-quoted strings.
      mkdir "$hdir/_udp_filtered"
      mv  "${f}_udp_filtered".pcap "$hdir/_udp_filtered"
      # !! `find` command removed here - there was never
      # !! a good reason for it to be *inside* the loop to begin with.
      # !! see below.
  done

  # !! Delete files now:
  # !! It looks like "$hdir/_udp_filtered" has no subdirectories, given that
  # !! you've just created it above, so we can simply use `rm`.
  # !! If you DO have subdirs., consider using `shopt -s globstar` 
  # !! and **/ (bash 4+).
  rm "$hdir/_udp_filtered/$nodeID.pcap"*

done
```

Comment: thank you for the comments. I just started bash scripting few days ago so any comment is appreciable. The problem is that removing `$nodeID.pcap` files works only for the last file in the loop. Instead of removing: `1.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap 3.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap 5.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap 7.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap 9.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap` only the last one `9.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap` is removed

Comment: If I put the `rm` line out of the loop, it works in the same way. I think there is something wrong with the `$nodeID` variable in the loop.

Comment: Place `set -x` at the top of your script or at least above the loop where `$nodeId` is set, which "[p]rint[s] commands and their arguments as they are executed." You'll be able to see what `$nodeID` is set to in each iteration.

Comment: Perhaps you don't need to solve the `$nodeId` problem, IF it's OK to simply delete all `{number}.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap` files, which the following command would do `(shopt -s extglob; xglob='+([0-9]).pcap_udp_filtered.pcap'; rm "$hdir/_udp_filtered/"$xglob)`

Comment: @marcin: P.S. I noticed that you've asked several questions without accepting any answers. The idea is to accept answers that solve your problem and up-vote others that are at least helpful - this benefits not only the people who answered, but the community at large.

Comment: I pushed "the tick" button next to the question. To vote i need at least 15 reputation points. What else could I do to accept answers?

Comment: @marcin: Thanks; clicking the "tick" marked the answer as accepted - which is the most important part in this case. Generally, you do not _also_ need to up-vote the answer you accept (but you can, if you particularly liked the answer) - up-votes are typically used for _other_ helpful answers, including answers to _other_ people's questions you think are helpful. As you've discovered, though, you'll need at least 15 points to up-vote.